# <-- operator in android graphics

Tags: android, graphics

```
 v1.addView(new TransfomedViewWidget(<-- (9)
            this,
            new Transformation() {<-- (10)
                @Override public String describe() { return "rotate(-30)"; }
                @Override public void transform(Canvas canvas) {
                    canvas.rotate(-30.0F);
                } }));
```

I am new to Java and android programming , can anyone tell me what this <-- operator means? I am getting error while trying to compile this in eclipse.

Comment: Looks like an annotation. I don't think its code.

Comment: If you copied it from some samples, then they might have numbered the lines so as to explain them later.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't part of the syntax, it loks like something else has put it there.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly it was a note or comment ... add `//` in front of them and try to compile again.